# Escaping backslash character remains

Tags: c#

This is really annoying :
I have the following string pattern :

```
"<{0} id=\""+"{1}"+ "\" class=\""+"{2}\""
```

and the result is : `"<{0} id=\"{0}"\" class=\"{2}\""`
I'ved tried replacing \ with empty character,tried writing (char)34 instead of \" but sill the same result.

Could someone please help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an '@' symbol out front by any chance? This works as expected: `MessageBox.Show("<{0} id=\"" + "{1}" + "\" class=\"" + "{2}\"");`

Comment: Where are you seeing this "result"? In the Visual Studio debugger? The debugger shows strings encoded (with backslashes and enclosing quotes) in C# syntax, exactly as in your "result" so you can see metacharacters, control characters, et al. If the debugger shows "id=\"{0}\"" then the string contains `id="{0}"` without backslashes. If it contained backslashes you would see "\\".

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.WriteLine("<{0} id=\"" + "{1}" + "\" class=\"" + "{2}\"");
    Console.WriteLine("<{0} id=\"{1}\" class=\"{2}\"");
```

ouput this:

```
<{0} id="{1}" class="{2}"
<{0} id="{1}" class="{2}"
```

which is perfectly normal (no backslash issue).

Comment: Sorry for posting this issue. A restart to Visual Studio solved the problem :D